# Lambdabot `sourcePlugin' failed with: state not initialized

Tags: haskell, lambdabot

When I install lambdabot on my archlinux machine, I get the following error when I want to access the source code of a function

`'sourcePlugin' failed with: state not initialized`

It seems I am not the only one with this problem -> https://wiki.debian.org/Haskell/CollabMaint/Lambdabot

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The very same problem faced here too with lambdabot 4.3.0.1. Have you received an answer or otherwise solved the problem? If you have, could you please share it?

Comment: @Gspia, have you tried manual build mentioned below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed lambdabot manually by first executing `git clone git://github.com/int-e/lambdabot.git`. After getting the package, it will give you the `lambdabot`, `lambdabot-core`, and various other packages that are needed for the build. I highly recommend you sandbox a directory and share the sandbox with all of the necessary packages. Manually building that version (used in #haskell), got all the associated plugins to work for me. If I tried installing automatically via `cabal install lambdabot`, I was able to reproduce your issue. If after manually installing the program, you find that your sourcePlugin is still not functioning properly, check your `$HOME/.lambdabot/State/` and look for the `source` file. If it is not there, transfer it from your sandboxed library to this directory (for me it was `$HOME/pathToMySandbox/lambdabot/share/i386-linux-ghc-7.6.3/lambdabot-5.0/State`. This should work for you.

UPDATE: In case this solution causes your `@run` or `>` not to work, see an updated solution posted by me at https://github.com/mokus0/lambdabot/issues/74

Answer (score 0):

Using the [lambdabot fork](https://github.com/int-e/lambdabot.git) an applying the fixes in http://adit.kasinoda.org/2014/06/28/lambdabot.html works for me.
I've installed lambdabot in a sandbox and commands **@src**, **@run** and **>** work fine.

EDIT: The fixes related in the web page are:

1. *Djinn* does not link because the cabal project specifies a bad **-Wl** option. This [repository](https://github.com/matematikaadit/djinn) contains the correction.
2. Add *lambdabot-trusted* as *lambdabot*'s dependency in *lambdabot/lambdabot/lambdabot.cabal*, and add the entry `"lambdabot-trusted"` in the `trustedPkgs` list of *lambdabot/lambdabot-haskell-plugins/src/Lambdabot/Config/Haskell.hs*.
3. Add the CPP extension (`{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}`) and constrain (GHC<7.8.2) the import of `Control.Monad.instances` in *lambdabot/labmdabot/State/Pristine.hs*:
4. Copy *lambdabot/labmdabot/State/Pristine.hs* in *lambdabot/labmdabot/State/L.hs*
5. Install lambdabot with cabal
6. After installing, copy the contents of *sandbox-dir/share/amd64-openbsd-ghc-7.6.3/lambdabot-5.0/State* in directory *~/.lambdabot/State*

Thanks [drs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1484957/drs)

Comment: Since links often go stale, [it is always preferred](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.